# Communicating with UDP between .Net and Simulink

Tags: .net, matlab, udp, simulink

I have a .net application that receives physics data from a racing simulator, and a Simulink model that filters accelerations to output motion cues for a motion platform.

I am having difficulty sending the data from the .net application to Simulink using UDP. I have been able to get data to show in a Scope block, but it is garbled and the numbers are completely different to what I am sending.

Can anyone advise on the best UDP Receive block to use (since there are several in different toolboxes), and if anything else needs to be done to send and receive the data correctly.

My current UDP send code looks like this:

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, 25000);
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(carphysics.AccG[2]); // data is a float
socket.SendTo(buffer, endpoint);
```

The data I am sending is usually less than 4, but the data showing on the scope in Simulink is often around 150, and outliers can blow out to the maximum.

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: The configuration for my current UDP Receive is below, this is the DSP system toolbox one.
[image]

Comment: Could you show the configuration of the UDP receive simulink block  ?

Comment: I've added the UDP config.

Comment: Things I'd do: Check contents of `buffer`, use `127.0.0.1` instead of accepting all, increase sample time, use a while loop in original .net code. If nothing works try receiving it using a C S-function (you need to code the logic)

Comment: you have a comment _"data is a float"_, you send the full byte array for each data, and on the receiving end you read `uint8`. Are you sure you convert these `uint8` back to float, and if yes is the endianess ok ?

Comment: Hoki, that's kind of where I'm falling down, if I change the type in the receive block to something like double, I don't get anything displayed on the scope. Also, how would I tell what the endianess should be?

Comment: The sample time looks very very small. Remember that UDP is not real-time, I don't think Simulink running on Windows can cope with this sort of sample time. I would try changing to 0.1s or even 1s to see if that improves things.

Comment: @am304, I agree, that was a result of playing around, increasing it resulted in less noise, but still incorrect values, which is my main issue. Getting the timing correct is secondary to actually getting the correct data.

Comment: I would focus on the data type issue: if you are sending a `float` but receiving a `uint8`, it's not surprise that the data received is incorrect. The data sent and received needs to be of the same data type. You need to investigate what's happening you configure the block to receive `double`.

Comment: @Steve. You can also read by `uint8` (because that's how they are sent anyway), but you have to rearrange them at the receiving end. Read 4 of them, then use the [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) function to convert these 4 bytes into a matlab `single`. If the endianess is wrong, use that in conjunction with the [`swapbyte`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html) function (as described in the typecast doc). As mentioned above, also try slower sampling speed, until you get your numbers right, then you can increase the speed incrementally.

Comment: @Hoki That lead me to the correct answer. I ended up using a Matlab function blcok to read the 4 bytes, then a Byte Unpack block to get the number back out. If you put what you wrote as an answer, I'll accept it.